# How do I stop overwriting arraylist?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, static

> I have used the input to get values and add it to ArrayList. When I input data for the second time, it overwrites the first data after entering second data. Unable to fix it.
>
> Student class

```
public class Student {
static int rollNumber, age;
static String firstName, lastName, gender;
public Student(int rollNumber, String firstName, String lastName, int age, String gender) 
 {
   this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
   this.age = age;
   this.gender = gender;
  }
}
```

> InputParticipant class

```
import java.util.*;
public class InputParticipant extends Student{
        public static String sportsEvent;
        public InputParticipant(int rollNumb, String firstName, String lastName,
        int age, String gender, String sportsEvent) 
        {
            super(rollNumber, firstName, lastName, age, gender);
            this.sportsEvent=sportsEvent;
        }
        public void elegibility()
        {
            System.out.print("Eligibility:");
            //50 meter race
            if(age>=10 && age<=12 && gender.equals("female") && sportsEvent.equals("50meterrace"))
            {
                System.out.println(" Yes ");
            }
            else if((age>=10 && age<=15) && sportsEvent.equals("100meterrace"))//100 meter race
            {
                System.out.println(" yes ");
            }
            else if(age>=15 && (sportsEvent.equals("400meterrace") || sportsEvent.equals("Juvelin") || sportsEvent.equals("discus")))//400 meter race, Juvelin and discus
            {
                System.out.println(" Yes ");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(" No (age:Min 10-12 for 50m race-female only, Min 10-15 for 100m race and Min 15 for 400m race, Juvelin and discus)");
            }
    
         }
         public static void main(String[] args) 
         {
             List<InputParticipant> stud=new ArrayList<InputParticipant>();
             InputParticipant i;
             i=new InputParticipant(rollNumber, firstName, lastName, age, gender, sportsEvent);
             Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
             while(true)
             {
                System.out.println("Enter the Student details:");
                System.out.print("roll number:");
                rollNumber=in.nextInt();
                System.out.print("First name:");
                firstName=in.next();
                System.out.print("Last name:");
                lastName=in.next();
                System.out.print("age:");
                age=in.nextInt();
                System.out.print("gender:");
                gender=in.next();
                System.out.print("sports event(50meterrace/100meterrace/400meterrace/Juvelin/discus):");
                sportsEvent=in.next();
                stud.add(i);
                List<InputParticipant> l=new ArrayList<InputParticipant>();
                l.addAll(stud);
                Iterator<InputParticipant> disp= l.iterator();
                while(disp.hasNext())
                {
                    InputParticipant st=disp.next();
                    System.out.println("Roll Number:"+st.rollNumber+"\nName: "+st.firstName+" "+st.lastName+"\nGender: "+st.gender+"\nAge: "+st.age+"\nSports Event:"+st.sportsEvent);
                    st.elegibility();
          System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Add new input to end?

Comment: When I enter first input values it gets added to arraylist. now, when I enter it second time, the first value gets overwrite displaying the second input twice. where in it should not happen.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. Most of the code here isn't relevant to the question. Additionally, please take the time to format the code as readably as possible.

Comment: Please also fix your indentation. Your IDE can do that for you.

Answer (score 2):

Because you create new object inside loop : 
List l=new ArrayList();

Try something like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<InputParticipant> stud=new ArrayList<InputParticipant>();
    //List<InputParticipant> l=new ArrayList<InputParticipant>();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Enter the Student details:");
        System.out.print("roll number:");
    rollNumber=in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("First name:");
    firstName=in.next();
    System.out.print("Last name:");
    lastName=in.next();
    System.out.print("age:");
    age=in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("gender:");
    gender=in.next();
    System.out.print("sports event(50meterrace/100meterrace/400meterrace/Juvelin/discus):");
    sportsEvent=in.next();
    stud.add(i);
    InputParticipant i = new InputParticipant(rollNumber, firstName, lastName, age, gender, sportsEvent);

    Iterator<InputParticipant> disp = l.iterator();
    while(disp.hasNext()){
        InputParticipant st=disp.next();
        System.out.println("Roll Number:"+st.rollNumber+"\nName: "+st.firstName+" "+st.lastName+"\nGender: "+st.gender+"\nAge: "+st.age+"\nSports Event:"+st.sportsEvent);
        st.elegibility();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try using Java POJO.

In your case, AFTER you get the values from Scanner, create a new Object and then add that object to your ArrayList.

```
i = new InputParticipant(rollNumber, firstName, lastName, age, gender, sportsEvent);
stud.add(i);
```

Not sure why you are creating another ArrayList inside your while loop, as while should only be used for gathering inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really help you fix the code because a lot is rather *strange* about it.

Why it seems you are always overriding has probably to do with making all class members of Student *static*, which means that every instance of the Student class will have the same name, firstname,...

-Maybe start by creating a Student class that only contains private members with getters and setters and a constructor for all those properties.

-Then create your main method in a separate Main class, this will prevent you from doing stuff you shouldn't be doing.

-In that method instantiate a List, AFTER this start a loop.

-In that loop you collect your data of 1 student into local variables (String name = in.readNext(); String firstName =....)

-Now you instantiate a Student object with the constructor, you just pass the local vars into it.

-Add the freshly created Student object to your list.

-When the loop is done, you should have a list filled with Students.

Answer (score 0):

The members of both the `Student` class and the `InputParticipant` class are static. Read up [static members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).
In other words, the `ArrayList` is not being overwritten, a static member is kind of like a shared variable across the different objects of the same class. If you assign something to a static member in one object, the member will have the new value in all the objects. Just remove the static keyword and make them instance members.

```
public class Student {
public int rollNumber, age;
public String firstName, lastName, gender;
public Student(int rollNumber, String firstName, String lastName, int age, String gender) 
 {
   this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
   this.age = age;
   this.gender = gender;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am aware of it. Is there any way to fix?